# Why does splitting a string with accents crash?

Tags: swift, split, foundation

This should be simple enough…

```
import Foundation

let str:String = "Beyonce\u{301} and Tay"
print(str)

print(str.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "e")))
```

Which compiles fine, until I run the executable:

```
// Beyoncé and Tay
// Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

I suspect Swift has a hard time dealing with the combining `'\u{65}'` accent mark, but given how much the language stresses its grapheme-based string model, I thought it would be pretty clear that splitting `"Beyonce\u{301} and Tay"` on `'e'` should just give `["B", "yonce\u{301} and Tay"]` since the `'e\u{301}'` should be interpreted as a single grapheme instead of an `'e'` plus a combining acute.

Splitting on a *single* character does not crash:

```
print(str.components(separatedBy: "e"))
// ["B", "yoncé and Tay"]
```

My swift version is

```
swiftc -version
Swift version 3.0-dev (LLVM 3e3d712024, Clang 09ad59b006, Swift fdf6ee20e4)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Comment: I get the output `["B", "yonc", "́ and Tay"]` when running in a Xcode command-line application.

Comment: @MartinR I am running swift `version 3.0-dev` on Linux

Comment: @MartinR but at any rate, that isn’t the correct output is it? `é` should be interpreted as a single atom, `'é' != 'e'`

Comment: Yes, but `CharactersSet` is "only" a wrapper for `NSCharacterSet` from Foundation, and `components(separatedBy:)` is probably bridged to `NSString` (which does not have the same Unicode capabilities as Swift `String`). – I can confirm the crash with Swift version 3.0.1 (swift-3.0.1-RELEASE) on Ubuntu Linux. Looks like a bug in the Foundation library on Linux.

Comment: @MartinR so is there a way to split a pure Swift `String` on a `Set<Character>` of delimiters? It appears that `.characters.split(separator:)` only takes a single `Character`.

Comment: There is `split(whereSeparator: { })` which takes a block.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130043/discussion-between-taylor-swift-and-martin-r).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is a bug in the Linux port for Swift. I won't address that in my answer. The code below was tested on Mac OS X.

You ran into normalization problem of Unicode. The letter `é` can be expressed in 2 ways, considered identical by Swift:

```
let s1 = "e\u{301}" // letter e + combining acute accent
let s2 = "\u{0e9}"  // small letter e with acute

s1.characters.count // 1
s2.characters.count // 1
s1 == s2            // true
```

That's because Swift's `String`, like its predecessor `NSString` has very good support for Unicode. But if you delve deeper, you start to see some differences:

```
s1.utf16.count // 2
s2.utf16.count // 1
```

So even when `s1` and `s2` are equal, they are stored differently: using 2 or 1 code points. `components(seperatedBy: )` is blind to this fact. It iterates over all the code points in your string and split if it finds the letter `e`. Converting between one form to another is called *normalization* and affects how the function works:

```
let str1 = "Beyonce\u{301} and Tay"
let str2 = str1.precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping // normalize the string to Form C

let charset = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "e")
str1.components(separatedBy: charset) // ["B", "yonc", "́ and Tay"]
str2.components(separatedBy: charset) // ["B", "yoncé and Tay"]
```

References:

- [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)
- [Unicode Normalization Forms](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/)